# Is the average of multiple function's minimum equivalent to the minimum of the average function of the multiple functions?

Tags: cross-validation, model-averaging

Sorry if the wording is confusing, I feel it accurately articulates the question although being a bit of a head teaser.

Essentially I am running many cross-validated models. Each model produces a (marginally) different curve for the loss function against penalty parameter. I know I can average all these functions and find the minimum to obtain my desired value. What I would like to do, as it is computationally lighter, is to instead extract the minimum value for each function and then perform the averaging on these extracted values.

Intuitively, it seems this could be equivalent, but I can't think of how to show this rigorously. If anyone could confirm/deny my intuition through a mathematical proof, it would be greatly useful to me.

Thanks

Comment: The minimum of the averages could be greater than the average of the minimums. Take two functions f1, and f2. Say f1 =x  and f2 =x$^2$ both for 0<=x<=1.  Then both f1 and f2 have minimum equal to 0 and so their average is 0 but both f1 and f2 have averages greater than 0 and hence the minimum of the averages is also greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading, it sounds like you are talking about the argmin instead of the minimum (the value $x$ which minimizes $f(x)$, where $x$ is in your case the penalty parameter).

The argmin of $(x-1)^2$ is $x = 1$ and argmin of $3(x+1)^2$ is $x = -1$. So the average of the argmins is $0$. But the average of those two functions is $2x^2+2x+2$, which has an argmin at $-0.5$. So the argmin of averages isn't the average of argmins.